# "libs/collab" is no longer supported in AEM 6.1

Tags: java, aem

Does anyone know the equivalent library for:

- `/libs/collab/calendar/components/form/recurrence`
- `/libs/collab/calendar/components/form/icslink`

They are no longer supported by AEM 6.1.

I tried finding it in CRXDE but I failed to do so.

Comment: Hello ;) I think you should try to ask this question on software recommendations :)

Comment: Thanks on this, I'll post it there then. But if ever other has an idea on this question, please answer. :) @DawidPi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Removed:
    /libs/collab/calendar/components/form/recurrence
    /libs/collab/calendar/components/form/icslink
To be used:
    /libs/social/calendar/components/form/icslink
    /libs/social/calendar/components/form/recurrence

But the catch is, the last 2 mentioned components should be installed in AEM 6.1 copied from CQ 5.6.1.